# UrlProcessor warning for unity with Ready Player Me SDK during runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to load Avatar imported from Ready Player Me package via URL during runtime, but I got below warning and my project stopped after this, can anyone give an explanation why I get below warnings? I just use the Ready Player Me runtime script as the official manual told.

```
UrlProcessor.CreateFromUrl: LocalDirectory for local paths is not set. Defaulting to EditorDefaultLocalDirectory
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning (object)
ReadyPlayerMe.UrlProcessor:CreateFromUrl (string) (at Assets/Plugins/Ready Player Me/Runtime/Operations/UrlProcessor.cs:49)
ReadyPlayerMe.UrlProcessor:Create (string) (at Assets/Plugins/Ready Player Me/Runtime/Operations/UrlProcessor.cs:36)
ReadyPlayerMe.AvatarLoader:ProcessUrl (string) (at Assets/Plugins/Ready Player Me/Runtime/AvatarLoader.cs:78)
ReadyPlayerMe.AvatarLoader:LoadAvatar (string) (at Assets/Plugins/Ready Player Me/Runtime/AvatarLoader.cs:49)
Runtime:LoadAvatar () (at Assets/Scripts/Runtime.cs:27)
Runtime:Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Runtime.cs:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

the url processor method changed, upload the ready player me sdk to solve

Comment: need more detail and clarity

Comment: Url of the avatar has changed recently, rpm has new cloud i think. Also the avatarloader script has changed, so you have to search for the last sdk version and upload the scripts on your project